Extra underline on table for Outlook Windows email clients
The table on Outlook Windows email clients is rendering weirdly. It's showing an extra underline on the date field.
Current table format
How can I remove the unwanted line on Outlook Windows clients?
I tried to isolate where the line is coming from by deleting all of the borders but the underline moved to the time field. The table is showing up fine on Gmail and Apple Mail desktop clients - it's mainly occurring on Outlook 2019, Outlook 2021 and OL Office 365.
Here's my HTML:


<td class="pad">
  <table style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; direction: ltr; background-color: transparent; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; color: #242a56; text-align: left; letter-spacing: 0px;"
    width="100%">
    <tbody style="vertical-align: top; font-size: 13px; line-height: 150%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-break: break-word; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-right: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;background-size: auto; background-color: #242a56;color:#fff;" width="50%"><strong>Property</strong></td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-break: break-word; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-right: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;" width="100%">%%Lead:Location__r:Name%%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-break: break-word; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-right: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;background-color: #242a56;color:#fff;" width="50%"><strong>Date</strong></td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-break: break-word; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-right: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;" width="100%">%%=Format(Lead:Tour_Date__c, "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy")=%%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-break: break-word; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-right: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;background-color: #242a56;color:#fff;" width="50%"><strong>Time</strong></td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-break: break-word; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-right: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;" width="100%">%%Lead:Tour_Start_Time__c%%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </td>



